# How to enter more than 1 serial number in a Lenovo warranty information site?

Tags: python, http, export-to-csv

I'm supposed to collect the Lenovo Warranty information from Lenovo website using python code and convert to csv file and use power BI to visualize the data...

I have multiply serial numbers that i have to find a way to enter them on the website and create a simply form of excessing them automatically in 1 button and it views the whole warranty information.

Comment: You want to take a look at Selenium, a library used to interact with a browser. As per writing code, Stack Overflow isn't a platform to request for code, but to ask for direction on specific problems. This is a bit too vast, you'll have to show us some code and a specific problem we can help with!

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ is the library I am referring to. This sounds like a good starting point for you.